# Same interface in 2 different dependency issue

Tags: java, gradle, dependency-management

I have conflict problem with dependencies.

My project has two dependencies like this:

```
dependencies {

  provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'

  compile files('path/to/ABC.jar')

}
```

`ABC.jar` has its own dependency to `javax.servlet:servlet-api`:

```
dependencies {

  provided group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'servlet-api', version: '2.5'

}
```

Here is the problem I am dealing with; I need to use `ServletContext` interface which is provided by both **servlet-api** libraries and the compiler uses wrong one.

Gradle auto-resolves version conflicts as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:version_conflicts).

But in my case it doesn't help, because it only works when a dependency has two different versions. In this case; although it's a newer version issue, the name has changed from `javax.servlet:servlet-api` to `javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api`. So gradle doesn't auto-resolve this conflict, because it doesn't seem to be a version issue.

The thing I tried was using excluding transitive dependency as described [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#sub:exclude_transitive_dependencies).

```
compile files('path/to/ABC.jar') {
    exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
}
```

But it didn't work, it seems `exclude` doesn't work on local 'jar' files.

Now, I don't know what else to do.

How can I exclude a dependency of a dependency which is added as a local file?

(If the first question doesn't have any answer yet) How can I say to the compiler to use the correct `ServletContext` interface?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`compile files('path/to/ABC.jar')` is a file dependency, a file dependency does not have any dependency information, so it does not introduce transitive dependencies. If this `ABC.jar` is a "fat" jar that has the dependency-classes included in the JAR, it is not suited for usage in something like Gradle, Maven or Ant/Ivy that is supposed to handle the dependencies. You would have to use a proper "thin" version of the dependency with the dependencies properly declared, or you need to "repackage" that JAR in your build script to exclude the dependency classes you don't want to pull in. No dependency management can do this for you.

You can execute `gradlew dependencyInsight --configuration runtime --dependency javax.servlet:servlet-api` or `gradlew dependencies --configuration runtime` to find out where the dependency really comes from.

---

Actually your example should not even compile if I see it correctly, because it should most probably be

```
compile files('path/to/ABC.jar'), {
    exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
}
```

or

```
compile(files('path/to/ABC.jar')) {
    exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
}
```

But as I said, with a local file dependency there are no transitive dependencies, so an exclude does not make sense at all anyway.

---

To make the Gradle version conflict magic work, you can simply tell Gradle that those libraries are actually the same library just with different coordinates by using a module replacement like

```
dependencies {
    modules {
        module('javax.servlet:servlet-api') {
            replacedBy 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api'
        }
    }
}
```

Then Gradle sees them as the same library and can do its version conflict resolution magic. Whether the library that needs the old version still works with the new version is a different topic that you have to check and / or try yourself. This like always depends on whether the new version is backwards compatible to the old version.

Answer (score 1):

I have no way to test this now, but I believe your syntax is wrong. I have some examples here that look different, in your case it would be:

```groovy
compile(files('path/to/ABC.jar')) {
    exclude group: 'javax.servlet'
}
```

As I say, I cannot test it now, check if it helps and give a comment.